# Select nodes containing a child with a class that contains X

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing, xpath-2.0

I got the following XML:

```
  <a> 
    <div class="from ng-binding">Stranger</div>  
    <div class="subject ng-binding">Hello there</div>  
    <div class="time ng-binding"</div> 
  </a>
```

I'm trying to select the a tag which has a child which class contains "subject" (so basically the a tag of this example).

I have tried the following:

```
//a[contains(.//div/@class,'subject')]
```

But it does not select anything.
I changed it to `//a[contains(.//div/@class,'from')]` and that works so I don't get what the issue is.
Shouldn't `.//`check all children of the node?

Comment: FYI, XPath doesn't select any *tags*. It operates on the logical structure of the XML, such as elements, not on the surface structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want

```
//a[.//div[contains(@class, 'subject')]]
```

The contains() function only takes the first item in its first argument, so if you pass `.//div/@class` as the first argument to `contains()`, you will only be testing the first result of `.//div/@class` instead of testing all of them.

In other words, the code you tried is essentially equivalent to

```
//a[contains((.//div/@class)[1],'subject')]
```

Comment: Actually, in XPath _2.0_ (as per the question tags) `contains(.//div/@class,'from')` ought to raise a type error, as the first argument of `contains` must be a sequence of no more than one item.

Comment: @IanRoberts: Good catch on the XPath 2.0 type error. I was going to look up the official reference, but didn't. I learned on XPath 1.0 and haven't ever completely updated my knowledge.